# Vitamin B food source

Tags: micronutrients, vegetarianism, vitamin-b

My question is very simple. What are some good vegetarian food sources for vitamin B? I'm asking this here because I tried to search it on the net but couldn't find much.

Comment: _I tried to search it on the net but couldn't find much_ Really? The search terms "vegetarian" and "vitamin b" on google retrieve more than 3 millions entries. "Shopping question" should really be avoided on Health SE. At least you could provide some links to the research you have already done and explain what is not clear for you. BW

Comment: @S.Victor They're all contradictory. For instance, I've learnt here that there is vegetarian source for active B12. Google search gives you tens of them. The percentage content is different on every site, sometimes too different. So, I had discredit that research, look for a reliable source. And ofcourse, I can't surf through 3 million search results now, can I?

Comment: Actually, this wasn't my point to say you should surf through 3 millions entries. I just wanted to underline the inconsistency of your statement *"I'm asking this here because I tried to search it on the net but couldn't find much"*. As I said, you should at least provide some examples of the links you have found, their contents and what seems "contradictory" to you. Finally, the first hits for the google search retrieves informations from websites such as WebMD and NHS Info for example, which are reliable sources. BW

Comment: @S.Victor alright, I didn't about these sites. Only now I have learnt about their reliability. My bad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because are off topic unless directly connected to medical treatment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here on [Nutrients Review](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/vitamins) you have lists of foods high in individual vitamins B.

Here on [US Department of Agriculture (USDA)](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/index) are more detailed lists of foods high in individual vitamins and other nutrients.

Roti/chapati, seeds and other plant foods do not contain vitamin B12. As a vegan, you can get vitamin B12 by eating foods that have vitamin B12 added or by taking vitamin B12 supplements. You can get other B vitamins and other nutrients from natural foods.

If a certain food is low in vitamins B or other vitamins, it does not mean it's bad. It's not important how much vitamins a particular food has, but how much vitamins is in your diet (all foods together). You need to get all vitamins regularly, but this does not mean you need to get every single vitamin every single day.

The [Vegetarian Resource Group (vrg.org)](http://www.vrg.org/nutrition/b12.php) and [VeganHealth.org](http://veganhealth.org/articles/vitaminb12) seem to be reliable sources of nutrition info for vegans.

Answer (score 2):

The best are deactivated yeast or the extract and
Sunflower seeds(Source USDA) http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3076/2

Other choices(Source USDA) but not limited to; include
Pumpkin seeds 
Peanuts
Sesame

Herbs are very good sources of all nutrients; look through these herbs (Source;USDA)
http://www.nutrition-and-you.com/healthy-herbs.html

Answer (score 1):

Vitamin B is a misnomer, think of it not as 1 vitamin but as "B Vitamins", because there are 8 that are essential to good micro-nutrition.

B vitamins are found in whole unprocessed foods. Processed carbohydrates such as sugar/white flour tend to have lower B vitamin than their unprocessed counterparts. For this reason, it is required by law in many countries (including the United States) that the B vitamins thiamine, riboflavin, niacin, and folic acid be added back to white flour after processing. This is sometimes called "Enriched Flour" on food labels.

Good sources for B vitamins include legumes (pulses or beans), whole grains, potatoes, bananas, chili peppers, tempeh, nutritional yeast, brewer's yeast, and molasses. You can find this information by reading the labels of these products.

**So far so good for vegans.**

The B12 vitamin is of note because it is not available from plant products, making B12 deficiency a legitimate concern for vegans.

However, manufacturers of plant-based foods will sometimes report B12 content, leading to confusion about what sources yield B12. The confusion arises because the standard US Pharmacopeia (USP) method for measuring the B12 content does not measure the B12 directly. Instead, it measures a bacterial response to the food. Chemical variants of the B12 vitamin found in plant sources are active for bacteria, but cannot be used by the human body. This same phenomenon can cause significant over-reporting of B12 content in other types of foods as well.

Because B-vitamins are water soluble and readily excreted if they are over complimented.

**Recommendation for vegetarians/vegans is to supplement Vitamin B12. The rest of the B vitamins should be obtained through legumes (pulses or beans), whole grains, potatoes, bananas and chili peppers.**

Comment: The flour we use comes from grinding raw wheat from a nearby Grinder. So does it satisfy my needs for B Vitamins - {B12}? And yes, wheat breads(it's called roti I here)  are consumed three times a day.

Comment: If you haven't removed the bran and germ from the wheat before processing it then you can consider it "whole grain". As I said, bread alone will not completely satisfy your needs for B Vitamins. Bread/Roti will only give you B3 and B6.

Comment: What about seeds?

Comment: Google/Wolfram is your friend, I'm not about to do the analysis for you on your entire diet, consult/pay a nutritionist.

Comment: Haha, they didn't turn out to be very friendly, that'd why I came here. Nevermind. :)